# Dynamic changing background Grid

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to change the background of a grid containing an image and a textblock dynamicly with a specific duration and a nice animation (like tiles for exemple), let's say every 30 seconds, from a flux XML. any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tile control from [coding4fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/). See [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Getting-Started-with-the-Coding4Fun-toolkit-Tile-Control)

For dynamic update:
1. Create a dispatcher timer and update the tile property in callback
(Or)
2. Bind tile background dependency property to Image source property in a viewmodel. As long as you figure a way to update viewmodel, the ui will get refreshed.

Comment: i'm not talking about tiles, but i need the same behavior into a grid into the page of the application.

Comment: Did you read the provided page? *Basically Tile is an UI component that looks like the well known windows phone application tiles **but can be used internally inside** windows phone applications*, This is what you need.

Comment: ok but how can i make it change automaticly from an xml flux switch a specific duration?

Comment: For dynamic stuff I would look into creating a ObservableCollection and create an ViewModel and then a PropertyChangedEventHandler. this together with an timer to update every xx seconds the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Have-you try one method? have you search on the web ?

For tiles effect (and more effects...)  you want  use [Telerik Rad control](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) (animation named [HubTile](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx#hubtile)) but isn't free.. you want to try the trial version :)

Comment: sorry but i'm not talking about tiles, i need this behavior into the front page of the application

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your first question ( I'm not fluent in english) if you want to learn how change you application tiles, you can read [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202979(v=vs.92).aspx) else, can you retrieved your question more precisely please. :)

Comment: ok,i'll try to make it simple, i want the same behavior of tiles into the phone applicationPage. wich means a grid containing a textblock and an image changing y binding to flux xml.